# How to get data from table using GROUP BY and ORDER BY keyword?

Tags: php, mysql

I have following tables with columns :

1) users

```
user_id  username
```

2) projects

```
p_id   p_name
```

3) project_status

```
psdi    p_id    cdid   cid   sid  short_list   res_sent   status_date
```

4) company

```
cid   company_name
```

5) status

```
sid    status_name    status_order    is_cv_sent
```

6) projects_log

```
pl_id   cdid    project_name     p_id   user_id   status   date_time
```

Now, in this `projects_log` table there are same `p_id` value exist.

**I want to show all unique `p_id` with latest `date_time`.** as DESC order where `pl.cdid = $cdid`

I am using following query but can't get the results. It's not showing me all unique `p_id` as `date_time` DESC order :(

```
$get_log = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT 
    pl.*, 
    u.username, 
    p.p_name, 
    c.company_name, 
    s.status_name, 
    ps.* 
    FROM projects_log AS pl 
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.user_id =  pl.user_id 
    LEFT JOIN projects AS p ON p.p_id = pl.p_id     
    LEFT JOIN project_status AS ps ON ps.p_id = pl.p_id 
    LEFT JOIN company AS c ON c.cid = ps.cid 
    LEFT JOIN status AS s ON s.sid = ps.sid 
    WHERE pl.cdid = '$cdid' GROUP BY pl.p_id
    ORDER BY pl.pl_id DESC ");
```

Comment: Consider providing proper CREATE and INSERT statements AND a desired result

Comment: @Strawberry Updating my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using below query you will able to achieve group by p_id and will able to get values of max date_time row.

```
$get_log = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT 
    pl.*, 
    u.username, 
    p.p_name, 
    c.company_name, 
    s.status_name, 
    ps.* 
    FROM (
        select MAX(date_time) as MaxDateTime,p_id from projects_log group by p_id
    ) as mpl join projects_log AS pl on mpl.MaxDateTime = pl.date_time and mpl.p_id = pl.p_id
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.user_id =  pl.user_id 
    LEFT JOIN projects AS p ON p.p_id = pl.p_id     
    LEFT JOIN project_status AS ps ON ps.p_id = pl.p_id 
    LEFT JOIN company AS c ON c.cid = ps.cid 
    LEFT JOIN status AS s ON s.sid = ps.sid 
    WHERE pl.cdid = '$cdid'
    ORDER BY pl.pl_id DESC ");
```

Comment: WOW, I think it's working. Let me check again...but can you tell me what is the problem in my code ?

Comment: When we are doing group by with a column then it will fetch values from any row of that particular type. To get the values of the row having max date should have to use self join as I have used in above query. Don't forget to accept my answer if it worked fine.

Comment: I have found an issue. It's not getting `status_name` from `status` table Please check it.

Comment: ...Yes it's not showing status_name value from status table.

Comment: Does status table having record for that particular p_id? and Does the project_status table having record for the p_id having max date?